# How to implement "Collapsible navigation items" as described in the design guide?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

The section "Collapsible navigation items" of https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Content
specifies

> "Collapsible navigation items are split. Use the left side for navigation and the right to collapse and expand items." Along a [very clear illustration](http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_collapse.png).

However it does not seem possible to implement this recommended behaviour...

I cannot find a way to differentiate a click on the indicator to a click on the "left side of the navigation item".
I guess I could add an image view in the group view and implement the "collapse/expand" logic myself, but I find it odd that the design guide recommends something that goes against how the platform works.

So I guess I am missing something... Is it possible to implement this design pattern using the standard group indicator ?

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129402/navigation-drawer-collapsible-items) has already been asked, but there is no answer so far.

Thanks in advance for any clarification

Comment: The question link you have given is doesn't exist anymore. Btw did you get an efficient solution for this?

Comment: Actually no, I always show the sub items now...